# Do capacitors in series and parallel finish charging at the same time?

Tags: circuit-analysis, capacitor

Question:
Will capacitors that are in series and/or parallel with different capacitances all finish charging at the same time?

My thinking:
I believe they will as they will share the same time constant in an RC circuit and thus will take the same amount of time (Please correct if wrong)

I'm simply looking for a yes/no type response as I'm not sure if my thinking is correct.

Comment: Yes because in parallel voltage is the same. In series, current is the same. For series, zero current = charging has stopped. For parallel, same voltage = they are charging together so when one stops so does the other. Note that fully charged does not necessarily mean same voltage (i.e. it does in parallel but not in series). It just means no more increase in voltage.

Comment: Yes because C1 and C2 in parallel is electrically equivalent to a single capacitor of value C1+C2. And in series is equivalent to a single cap of value C1 || C2.

Comment: What do you mean by "finish charging"? How do you know when a capacitor has finished charging?

Answer (score 3):

Capacitors in an RC arrangement will never finish charging, they will asymptotically approach a state where the current flowing in equals their internal leakage current.  In high speed applications the ESR and other factors will be significant.  And of course different size capacitors in series will charge to different voltages, so the answer to your question depends on how you interpret ’finish charging’.  Probably the short answer is ‘yes but’.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what do you mean.

Yes, if connected in parallel and you mean equal voltage. But it is to say, that having different capacitance, but equal potential, they will store different charge (q=CU), that means different amount of energy. So if you mean equal voltage - yes, they will charge equally; equal energy - no.

When connected in serial, idea is same, but now they should have equal charge and different voltage.

Also about tau: the transition process will end when energy capacitor with biggest energy potential (I mean both capacitance and inductivity now) will finish it's "charging", that means that the whole system will have the same potential energy as its power supply.